# I have 2 service bus, i have to set one of the service bus to maxConcurrentSessions to 1. how can i do that

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have 2 service bus SerBus1,SerBus2. I have to configure service bus (SerBus1) to limit the message to 1 at a time. how can i set in the host to consider only SerBus1 but not SerBus2? is there a possibility to name the id/name of the service bus.
Here is the code I have in the host. this applies to both the service bus. but i want only for SerBus1

{

```
"version": "2.0",
"extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
        "prefetchCount": 1,
        "messageHandlerOptions": {
            "autoComplete": true,
            "maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
            "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
        },
        "sessionHandlerOptions": {
            "autoComplete": true,
            "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
            "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
            "maxConcurrentSessions": 1
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`host.json` is applied on a Function App level. Every service bus triggered function will respect those settings. If you need to have different settings per function/triggering queue, you should split the Function App and configure each with the required concurrency.